# How pnpm handles node modules?

Tags: npm, npm-package, pnpm

Why pnpm?

can we use pnpm instead of npm ?

how its different from npm ?

How pnpm handles node modules?

Planning to implement it on a video chat application for micro repo architecture  used in backend(nodejs)

any suggestions for other libraries instead of pnpm and npm?

Comment: Why are you asking here? Why not read what they themselves say: https://pnpm.io/